# Problema logearme con MVC NET CORE en Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, rest, asp.net-core

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando un login con MVC net core y consumiendo un servicio Web API net core soy nuevo en esto.
Para eso he creado una **AREA** donde va ser la autentificación

Ya el servicio Web api esta funcionando correctamente lo hice una prueba con Postman es un metodo Authentication **POST**

lo que quisiera es una vez logearme en otra pagina se coloque su nombres del usuario, ya que el web api si se logea me devuelve una lista de sus datos del usuario y se muestre en un nueva página menu.

ya que las variables que se ingresan sale como null y eso que le coloco los valores

Controller AuthenticationController

```
[Area("Authentication")]
        public IActionResult Index()

        {
            return View();
        }


    [HttpPost]
    [Area("Authentication")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(UserViewModels usuario)
        {
            using (var cliente = new HttpClient())
            {
                cliente.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49793/api/Authentication/GetAuthentication");

                var postTask = cliente.PostAsJsonAsync<UserViewModels>("GetAuthentication", usuario);
                postTask.Wait();

                var result = postTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Authentication");

                }

            }
            return View(usuario);
        }
```

**ViewModels**

```
 public class UserViewModels
    {
        public string CodUsuario { get; set; }
        public string CodPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
  @model SistemaAlmacen.Areas.Authentication.ViewModels.UserViewModels

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<h4>UserViewModels</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CodUsuario" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="CodUsuario" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CodUsuario" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CodPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="CodPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CodPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Esto es la estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre se va ahi cuando le doy en el boton de login 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado en el Index del GET pasar un modelo nuevo? `UserViewModels usuario` ? ¿Podrías colocar el HTML generado?

Comment: @fredyfx si intente pero igual manera salen como null yo para el login he creado un AREA

Comment: @fredyfx aunque le puesto F12 no hay nada dentro del input lo que le escribo

Comment: eso es normal. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el HTML generado

Comment: @fredyfx ya lo edite mi pregunta puse la imagen de lo que envió en los input

Comment: al chat que hay varias cosas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo mostrado, te hace falta habilitar los TagHelpers. Un TagHelper es ese prefijo `asp-` para los elementos en el HTML.

Para habilitar, sigue lo siguiente:

Crea un archivo ViewImports:

```
Views/_ViewImports.cshtml
```

En ese archivo, agrega esto:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers
```

Más detalles: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2